# Disable mouse wheel scroll on QscrollArea

Tags: python, events, pyqt, mousewheel, qscrollarea

I would like to simply disable mouse wheel scroll on QScrollArea, in order to scroll down only by clicking on right scrollbar, but I can't find any solution on the Internet.

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
sa = pg.QtGui.QScrollArea()
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()    
sa.setWidget(win)
```

The problem is that I have a lot of graphs in my scroll area, and when I try to mousewheel on one of them, the page will scroll up or down together with the graph.
I can't find a method to call on "sa" to disable mouse wheel scroll.

I found some posts discussing about install event filter but I can't understand how to use them in this case. For example, I tried to use this:

```
sa.viewport().installEventFilter(???)
```

but I really didn't understand what arguments to pass and how to check the event.

Thank you in advance if you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea. Event-filtering requires an object that inherits `QObject` to watch for the relevant events. Such objects have an `eventFilter` method which can be overriden to provide custom handing of all events for the watched object. If this method returns `True` for a given event, it will not be propagated any further. Usually the main-window is used to provide the event-filtering, like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.widget = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.widget.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scroll.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel and
            source is self.scroll.viewport()):
            return True
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 400, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I just managed to resolve the Issue creating a class:

`class Scroller(pg.QtGui.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.QtGui.QScrollArea.__init__(self)

    def wheelEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel:
            ev.ignore()`

Then creating the object like this:
`sa = Scroller()`

I dunnò if this is the most correct way, but I think it's really simple

Comment: @EdoardoBianchi. The method I showed is just a simple (only six lines of code).

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to resolve this, using this solution:

```
class Scroller(pg.QtGui.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.QtGui.QScrollArea.__init__(self)
    def wheelEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel:
            ev.ignore()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
sa = Scroller() # <======
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()    
sa.setWidget(win)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the answer provided until now have a major issue: they only consider wheel events *within* the viewport of the scroll area.

This means that if the mouse is hovering a scroll bar, the wheel event will be directly processed by it and not ignored.

While this may be fine in some situations, it may not be ideal if you want to *completely* prevent mouse wheel scrolling.

Luckily, QAbstractScrollArea automatically installs its own event filter on its scroll bars, and, by default, all wheel events not accepted by the viewport contents are actually sent to the scroll bars.

We only need to override the event filter and "ignore" the event, which will work for wheel scrolling on *both* the viewport *and* the scroll bars.

```py
class Scroller(QScrollArea):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
            event.type() == event.Wheel and (
                obj == self.verticalScrollBar()
                or obj == self.horizontalScrollBar()
            )
        ):
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

By returning `True` we ensure that the widget will never receive that event; note that there is no need to call `event.ignore()` here: if the wheel event was received, it means that it hasn't been accepted yet.